# Change <input type="color"> appearance in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Our site is using the HTML input color. For Chrome it is using a much better interface:

[image]

**In Firefox:**

[image]

Now my question is, is there a way to use the same chrome appearance for firefox? Or is it like that due to browser specific?

Comment: You can use [pickr  https://simonwep.github.io/pickr/](https://simonwep.github.io/pickr/)..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the styling of the popup of the `<input type='color'>` element. It is all up to the browser. If you want it to look the same on all browsers you will have to use some sort of js library.